# Foreach loop to check the empty string and assign it a value c#

Tags: c#, encryption, foreach

I dont much idea about Foreach Loop

I have 4 String Variables and i am storing the encrypted values from app.config in those varialbles.My Work is to Detect if there is data in those 4 variables.Even if one doesnt have values i want to pass a default encrypted values to it.I started doing like this......

```
string EncValue = oEncrypt.EncryptBase64String("NO Data Found");
UpdateOrCreateAppSetting("UserName", ref MPScmUserName);
UpdateOrCreateAppSetting("Password", ref MPScmPassword);
UpdateOrCreateAppSetting("DBUserName", ref MPDbUserName);
UpdateOrCreateAppSetting("DBPassword", ref MPDbPassword);
var list5 = from docs in doc1.Descendants("appender").Elements()
                                            where docs.Name == "file"
                                            select docs;
var element5 = list5.FirstOrDefault();
MPLoadAppConfig = appConfigFile1;
MPErrorLog = element5.Attribute("value").Value;

string[] namesArray = new string[] {
         MPScmUserName,MPScmPassword,MPDbUserName,MPDbPassword};

foreach (string i in namesArray)
{
    if (i is string)
    {
        if (i == "")
        {
            i = EncValue.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

How should i assign default encrypted value to the strings in that array which is a empty string. Please Help me....

Comment: well, first, you don't need `if(i is string)` since its a string array. They have to be strings. Then, I would substitute `if(i=="") `with `if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(i))`. But structurally, I don't see anything else wrong with this.. What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to say  `if (i is string)` because it's already a string.

In another `if` block you may say

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(i))
{
}
```

or you may use:

```
string[] arr = new string[] { "","A"};

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(arr[i]))
                {
                    arr[i] = "Hello";
                }
            }
```

Comment: ok...How to set a Defualt value if one of the string is empty ?

Comment: Use for loop as I have given an example.

Answer (score 2):

No need for the `if (i is string)` part because you already know it's a `string`. You should probably also use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace();` to test for an empty string.

**Edit** (shameless copy from [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11658832/275643)):

```
for (int i = 0; i < namesArray.Length; ++i) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(namesArray[i]))
    {
        namesArray[i] = EncValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: How to set a Defualt value if one of the string is empty ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the variable in a `foreach` loop. Your code should give you the following compile error:

> Cannot assign to 'i' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

You could do this using LINQ:

```
namesArray = namesArray.Select(s => s == "" ? EncValue.ToString() : s).ToArray();
```

Alternatively you could use a simple `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < namesArray.Length; ++i) 
{
    if (namesArray[i] == "")
    {
        namesArray[i] = EncValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it on the `for` loop. The Linq option may not be available depending on the version of the .NET framework he's using.

Comment: However the Linq version is really elegant. I need a course on Linq. Are you available Mark? :)

Answer (score 2):

Looping on the string array and changing the value of current string doesn't means you are changing the value of the string inside the array. When foreach loops on your array it returns a new string instance in `i`, so changing that `i` don't change the value in namesArray.
You need a traditional for loop with an indexer to access directly to the namesArray

```
for(int i = 0; i < namesArray.Length; i++) 
{ 
    if (namesArray[i] == string.Empty) 
    { 
         namesArray[i] = EncValue.ToString(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] newNamesArray = 
       Enumerable.Select(namesArray, s => s == "" ? EncValue : s).ToArray();
```